# Only the first label is added to the BarChart

Tags: ios-charts

I want to create bar chart. I am using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and this is my code on `viewDidLoad()`

```
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"]        
xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
```

My problem is that only the first bar has a label 'Jan' on the X axis.

This is the setData code

```
func setDataCount(count: Int, range: Double){

        let barWidth = 8.5
        let spaceForBar =  10.0;

        var yVals = [BarChartDataEntry]()


        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(0) * spaceForBar, y: 9.1))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(1) * spaceForBar, y: 5.4))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(2) * spaceForBar, y: 3.9))

        var set1 : BarChartDataSet!


        if let count = barChartView.data?.dataSetCount, count > 0{
            set1 = barChartView.data?.dataSets[0] as! BarChartDataSet
            set1.values = yVals
            barChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
            barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }else{
            set1 = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "")


            var dataSets = [BarChartDataSet]()
            dataSets.append(set1)

            let data = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)


            data.barWidth =  barWidth;

            barChartView.data = data

        }
    }
```

Comment: How many bars you can see on bar chart ? 1 or 12 ?

Comment: I see the 3 bars I am appending on yVals

Comment: Have you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For Above Issue your adding only 3 dataEntry into DataSet so its showing only 3 bars follow below dynamic code

```
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
```

**//This soud be dynamic not static**

```
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
```

Hope you can understand whats the problem with Bar chart dataset.

Let me know if you required any help on above code.